# wordpress php function file causes error on cart page -

Tags: php, wordpress, function

In wordpress the function file saves fine but it causes an error on cart page.

I am not sure which part of the various functions I have added causes the error on my cart page. Using WP-debug I can see it is from this function file that I have various snippets implemented.
I tried stripping each function/action to find the error but it just changes the Wp-debug error to another error listing the next function as the issue

Fatal Error:  Cannot redeclare wt_pklist_add_custom_css_packingslip() (previously declared in /home/679610.cloudwaysapps.com/cvkdbejjpf/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/functions.php:63

Here is the code from the function file...

thanks for the help!

```
    <?php

function divi__child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'divi__child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
 

function wc_remove_image_effect_support() {

    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wc_remove_image_effect_support', 100 );


     


function product_video($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
{
return get_field('product_video');
}
add_shortcode('productvideo', 'product_video');



function product_video2($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '')
{
return get_field('product_video2');
}
add_shortcode('productvideo2', 'product_video2');


add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {

    // HERE Set minimum cart total amount
    $minimum_amount = 140;

    // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
    if( $cart_subtotal < $minimum_amount  ) {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . sprintf( __("A minimum total purchase amount of %s is required to checkout."), wc_price($minimum_amount) ) . '<strong>', 'error' );
        }
    
    
    


/* Display Add to cart button on archives */ 

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);


//* Fix PDF output ORDER Packing Slip */ 

add_filter('wf_pklist_add_custom_css','wt_pklist_add_custom_css_packingslip',10,3);
function wt_pklist_add_custom_css_packingslip($custom_css,$template_type,$template_for_pdf)
{
    if($template_type=='packinglist')
    {
        if($template_for_pdf)
        {
            $custom_css.='.wfte_rtl_main{"Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif !important;}
            .wfte_shipping_address{"Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif !important; line-height:14px !important; font-size:13px !important;}
            .wfte_company_logo_extra_details{"line-height:10px !important; font-size:13px !important; margin-left:8px !important;}
            .wfte_product_table_body td {"line-height:10px !important; font-size:13px !important;}
            .wfte_order_number{ font-size:15px !important; font-weight:bold !important; }
.wfte_invoice_date{ font-size:14px !important;}
.wfte_order_date{ font-size:14px !important;}
            ';
        }
    }
    return $custom_css;}

    
//======================================================================
// CUSTOM FOOTER
// Adds a layout to your before cart
//======================================================================
function mp_add_custom_cart() {
    echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="2680"][/et_pb_section]');
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals', 'mp_add_custom_cart' );

                        



/**
 * Disable native lazy loading on images with a class of 'no-lazy'.
 * @param mixed $value 
 * @param mixed $image 
 * @param mixed $context 
 * @return mixed 
 */
function remove_lazy_loading_by_class( $value, $image, $context ) {
    if ( 'the_content' === $context ) {
         if ( false !== strpos( $image, 'no-lazy' ) ) {
              return false;
         }
    }
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr', 'remove_lazy_loading_by_class', 10, 3 );

            
    }
 // END
    ?>
```

Comment: That means your function `wt_pklist_add_custom_css_packingslip` is declared somewhere else. Remove it, or change the name and the function call in the preceding hook.

Comment: I did remove this function from the file and tested it, but It gives me the same error listing the next function as the issue.

Comment: I also removed all the functions and then I do not get the error - so I believe that means 1 of them must be the culprit.